# Open Source showing FPS text overlay, for any fullscreen app

Tags: open-source, performance-analysis

I'm looking for an open-source software that, whenever you are in any fullscreen app, shows the current FPS in a corner.

It must be open-source because I only want the software to study the code.

It can run on Linux or Windows, I don't mind.

Comment: Any kind of app, for instance games, video players or VM players, whose source code you don't have, right?

Comment: Yes. According to my research, it's about "hooking a direct3d function call" if it can help...